# WF 4: difference between ActivityAction or ActivityFunc and child activity

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am new to Workflow foundation and want to understand the purpose of `ActivityAction` and `ActivityFunc` and how it differs from having child activities instead.

As far as I can understand child activities may exist in some composite `NativeActivity` and have to be scheduled by it. So child activities *may* be used by `NativeActivity` as event handlers during its execution. So for example this NativeActivity may run some long running computation and schedule its child when it finishes.

`ActivityAction` and `ActivityFunc` (func returns a result and action does not) exist for the same purpose - to enable plugging custom handlers in the course of execution defined in the `NativeActivity`. The difference is that those are strongly typed and look more like contract declared by its parent.

So I came to conclusion that the main difference is strong typing and ActivityFunc/Action may be swapped with child activities. Is my understanding wrong or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of ActivityAction and ActivityFunc are that you can share data between your activity and the child ones. Most of the time you don't need to and you can just schedule a child activity and it can use InArguments to get at the data. There are some cases though, like a ParallelForEach where the parent can't just populate a Variable as each child is scheduled in parallel. In that case you want to pass the data when you schedule the child activity. And that is where the ActivityAction comes in.

In most cases you should not need to use ActivityAction and ActivityFunc though.

Comment: I've found that I need it all the time, as passing values into and getting results back from child activities is a very common pattern in my workflows.  It is also very robust, whereas the "variables collection" method of exposing values to child activities is *not*.  I've always found that WF4 chokes with "variable scope" errors with variables.

Comment: I normally just use In/OutArguments in the child activity and provide an activity designer so you can hook them up at design time like any other activity. Either approach works so I guess it is a case of personal preference.